# How to make Spring SimpleFormController work with HTTP Get requests?

Tags: java, spring

I have Spring SimpleFormController which currently works for POST requests.
I want to change the form submission to GET. So I changed the html form method="post" to method="get".

**After the change, I want processFormSubmission method to be invoked.
However its not.**

Can you please tell what I am doing wrong here?

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;

public class VehicleDescController extends SimpleFormController
{
    protected ModelAndView processFormSubmission(
        final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
        final Object command, final BindException errors) throws Exception
    {
        ....
    }
}

    <bean name="/vehicleDesc.html"
class="com.xxx.VehicleDescController">
    <property name="commandName" value="lotSeller"/>
    <property name="commandClass" value="com.xxx.LotSeller"/>
    <property name="formView" value="xxxTheBasics"/>
    <property name="viewName" value="xxxVehicleDesc"/>
    <property name="imageUploadViewName" value="imageUpload"/>
    <property name="vixErrorView" value="xxxVIXError"/>
    <property name="assignmentEntryService" ref="xxxService"/>
    <property name="referenceDataService" ref="referenceDataService"/>
    <property name="xxxReferenceDataService" ref="xxxReferenceDataService"/>
    <property name="messageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
    <property name="xxxService" ref="xxxService"/>
    <property name="validator" ref="xxxEntryValidator"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Sanity Check: Are you actually working on an old project and locked into using the stuff, or are you just getting started and followed a seriously out-of-date tutorial?

Comment: @Affe  Its very old project and there is requirement to change from POST to GET

Comment: Just thought I'd check :)  Most questions these days about Spring 2 API are from newbies who followed an old tutorial and don't know they're using massively deprecated stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple:

```
@Override
protected boolean isFormSubmission(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return true;
}
```

Will tell it to always follow the submit workflow of the controller.  Obviously if there are both "Submits" and also "normal" GETs that come into this URL, you will have to examine the request and figure out the difference!